# Тебе можно выходить гулять(,) только взяв свой телефон(,) полностью его зарядив!

Tags: запятые, деепричастный-оборот

На этих деепричастных оборотах делается акцент, и их, так как они — главные, убрать вообще никак нельзя (ни один!). Не нужны запятые?

> Тебе можно выходить гулять(,) только взяв свой телефон(,) полностью его зарядив!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я подумал над этим, смог разобраться, теперь помогу разобраться и вам.

Ваше предложение безличное, а в безличном предложении нередко бывают тесные связи с СИС (составными именными сказуемыми), если смысл в них.

Можно из **[справочника Розенталя (примечание к пункту 4)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113)** взять такое (безличное) предложение, где смысл в обороте:

*Это упражнение делают стоя на вытянутых носках*.

Розенталь объяснил, что смысл именно в том, **как** делают упражнение.

Попробуем по очереди разобраться с каждым оборотом в вашем примере:

*Тебе можно выходить гулять только взяв свой телефон* — суть в том, **когда именно** можно выходить гулять; здесь тесная связь возможна.

*Тебе можно выходить гулять полностью его зарядив* — суть снова в обороте; тесная связь возможна.

Сливаем всë в одно — получаем:

*Тебе можно выходить гулять только взяв свой телефон, полностью его зарядив!* — да, второй связан со сказуемым, но они однородны, поэтому вторая запятая обязательна.

Тесная связь второго оборота с первым также не проходит. Пробуем так:

*Взять свой телефон_ полностью его зарядив* — сложно сориентироваться, еще уменьшаем:

*Взять телефон_ зарядив* — не очень хорошо сочетаются глаголы *взять* и *зарядить*.

Так что тесная связь может быть только с составным именным сказуемым, но запятая ставится всë равно.

---

Приходим к единственному варианту, где оба оборота тесно связаны со сказуемым:

***Тебе можно выходить гулять только взяв свой телефон, полностью его зарядив!***

Answer (score 2):

Я бы фразу с таким содержанием записала так (**с союзом И)**:

*Тебе можно **выходить** гулять, // **только взяв** свой телефон, предварительно полностью его **зарядив**!*

Не обособлять деепричастные обороты  в этом предложении **НЕЛЬЗЯ!**

Наречие "предварительно" нужно для того, чтобы показать **последовательность** действий:  нужно взять, но перед этим зарядить.

**Пояснение**

1. Здесь нет обстоятельства **образа действия:** гулять (как?), но есть обстоятельство **условия:**

*Тебе можно выходить гулять при условии, **если** ты возьмешь свой телефон и  **при этом** полностью его зарядишь.*

2. У Розенталя в этой теме говорится о необособленных **одиночных** деепричастиях, а необособление деепричастных **оборотов** (тем более **распространенных**) встречается редко. Кроме того, оборот является обстоятельством **образа действия** (как?) с **качественным** значением.

**Пункт 3** (**Розенталь,** [**Деепричастные конструкции**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113)):

Но (**при тесном слиянии** оборота со сказуемым): Они встретились только будучи уже взрослыми. Встретились (какими?), **качественное** значение оборота. Также значение **времени (когда?).**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Обычно не обособляются **нераспространенные** обороты на основе деепричастий **несовершенного** вида, отвечающие на **вопрос КАК?)**

**Пункт 4 (Примечание)**:

Если деепричастный оборот (обычно **со значением обстоятельства образа действия**) тесно связан по содержанию со сказуемым и образует **смысловой** центр высказывания:

(1) **Поза**, в которой она сидела (как?): Она сидела  чуть **откинув голову** (Марк.) — указывается, что она не просто сидела, а сидела **с откинутой головой**;

(2) Жизнь безо всяких знакомств (как?); Жили Артамоновы ни с кем **не знакомясь**.

(3) Поза (как?): Это упражнение делают **стоя** на вытянутых носках — смысл сообщения в том, каким образом делают упражнение;

(4) Походка (как?): Старик шёл **прихрамывая** на правую ногу;

(5) Способ получения знаний (как?): Студенты приобретают знания не только **слушая** лекции, но и **выполняя** практические работы;

(6) Поза (как?): Писал он обычно **наклонив** голову;

(7) Чувства (как?): **Не унижая** себя говорю, а говорю с болью в сердце (М. Г.);  Однор. отношения с обстоятельством.

(8) Походка (как ходил?): Огромного роста, редкой силы, волосатый, он ходил по земле **наклоня** голову, как бык (М. Г.);

(9) Поза (как?): Яков сидел **опустив** ноги (М. Г.).

В заданном предложении эти условия **не соблюдаются**, поэтому обороты **обособляются**.  Одной тесной связи **недостаточно**, нужна соответствующая **грамматика**.

Образно говоря, ни одна тесная связь **не выдержит нагрузку** в виде таких оборотов.  Та же ситуация, что с **определительными** оборотами. Одного желания выразить **тесную связь** мало, надо подобрать **правильную форму.** И **одной логики** при рассуждениях тоже мало (по той же причине).

Comment: Добрый вечер, *Sharon*. Мне *кажется*, что надо подправить вот здесь: "Обособить деепричастные обороты в этом предложении НЕЛЬЗЯ!" (У Вас же ведь стоит запятая.) И вот здесь: "...последовательность действий: сначала зарядить, а потом брать". А в предлагаемом Вами предложении сначала берётся, а потом заряжается. Возможно, думаю, так: *Тебе можно выходить гулять, только полностью зарядив свой телефон и взяв его с собой!*

Comment: Спасибо большое за замечания. Одно я исправила, а в другом не хотелось бы менять авторскую последовательность, поэтому использовала наречие "предварительно".  Второй деепричастный оборот как бы уточняет ситуацию,  а первый ее определяет.

Comment: Ну да, можно и так.

Comment: Спасибо! Я очень благодарна своим редакторам)